# Trying to install faiss-gpu but error saying numpy not installed when it already is

Tags: python, numpy, faiss

Hi I am tryin to install pip install faiss-gpu

but am getting error telling me module 'numpy' not found when it has already been installed

I had previously installed faiss-cpu but wanted to use my gpu to increase the speed of the embedding process.

I am using a mac 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7 // Radeon Pro 560X 4 GB
Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB

Other packages i have installed in my venv are:

```
pip install pygpt4all==1.0.1
pip install pyllamacpp==1.0.6
pip install langchain==0.0.149
pip install unstructured==0.6.5
pip install pdf2image==1.16.3
pip install pytesseract==0.3.10
pip install pypdf==3.8.1
```

Help much appreciated

```
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/tombugeja/GPT4ALL_Tom/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/tombugeja/GPT4ALL_Tom/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Users/tombugeja/GPT4ALL_Tom/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/rg/j_3qm69919s9vvnrwzbn76580000gn/T/pip-build-env-532kod05/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/rg/j_3qm69919s9vvnrwzbn76580000gn/T/pip-build-env-532kod05/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/rg/j_3qm69919s9vvnrwzbn76580000gn/T/pip-build-env-532kod05/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/private/var/folders/rg/j_3qm69919s9vvnrwzbn76580000gn/T/pip-build-env-532kod05/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 6, in <module>**
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
      [end of output]**
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
**(myenv) tombugeja@Toms-MacBook-Pro-2 GPT4ALL_Tom % pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (1.23.5)
(myenv) tombugeja@Toms-MacBook-Pro-2 GPT4ALL_Tom % **
```